# Symfony JMSI18nRoutingBundle redirect with 301

Tags: symfony, redirect, routes, http-status-code-301

Is it possible to force the Bundle to redirect with a locale prefix and a 301 Status Code instead of a 302? It would be great for SEO.

Answer (score 0):

Quick peak at the code: yes. The permanent redirect happens inside the I18nRouter (and the redirect controller that is called there)

https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/blob/master/Router/I18nRouter.php#L258

You can override the I18nRouter (the match() method should be the relevant bit) and change `$permanent` to `false`

For more information about overriding in Symfony, check https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. I could do that but then I have to copy the code of this very long method and thats not save for updates (because it is a private method in the I18Router.php). Is there any other easy and save way to do it?

Comment: @Mojo Override the redirectAction in the controller and extend it (e.g. like you override controllers in the FOSUserBundle), but change the $permanent before you do the parent::redirectAction()

Comment: That's a good idea. But I can't get the override working. I created a new Bundle that implements the following function: 

`public function getParent() { return 'JMSI18nRoutingBundle'; }`

Then I created a Controller that extends the RedirectController from the Bundle and inserted the `redirectAction()` to override it. There I change the `$permanent` and call `return parent::redirectAction()` with the ne variable but nothing happens. I also inserted a `die()` to test it but the site is running as always.

Comment: If I interpret it right the bundle doesn't have any routing.yml in the expected folder: [https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/tree/master/Resources/config](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/tree/master/Resources/config)
There is only a services.xml. Any other location where it could be stored?

Answer (score -1):

You can simply change the response status code in the response listener.

Comment: Please explain that further - **how** should that be done?

Comment: @NicoHaase Check if the pathInfo is equal to '/' and then change the status code to be 301 `if ($event->getRequest()->getPathInfo() === '/') {
            $event->getResponse()->setStatusCode(301);
        }`

Comment: Please add all explanation to your answer by editing it